# Remove portion of some frames from a video

Tags: python, video, ffmpeg

Here is what I'm trying to do:
Imagine a video with 10 frames (0 = 1 frame)

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

with some frames selected(1 = 1 selected frame)

0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

and the end results should be this(all selected frames got removed from the video)

0 0 0 0 0 0 0

this is what I'm trying to do in python(with frames not times). Does anybody knows how I can do that?

Comment: What's the criteria for selecting the frames?

Answer (score 0):

Check out [OpenCV](https://docs.opencv.org/4.2.0/d6/d00/tutorial_py_root.html), it can split videos into frames, which you can then single out and remove if you want.

[Example tutorial which I got from a quick google search.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uL-wCzVMPsc)

Comment: I need to then have a video from the frames, the tutorial you linked left me with the frames I do want, but it's not as a video!

Comment: [This link here](https://theailearner.com/2018/10/15/creating-video-from-images-using-opencv-python/) should be of use to you. Just replace the part about _reading in images from files_ with whatever _array of frames_ you've created in your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ffmpeg within a Python wrapper to manipulate the video.

This approach allows you leverage the ffmpeg command line functionality and the wide community of ffmpeg expertise, although if you have to analyse and manipulate the frames then, OpenCV as mentioned in other answer, is worth considering.

There are several ffmpeg wrappers for Pithing but the following is a well supported example:

- https://github.com/kkroening/ffmpeg-python

To select specific frames to include or exclude from your output you can use the 'select' filter in ffmpeg which is documented here:

- https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#toc-select_002c-aselect

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
ffmpeg  -t 00:00:01 -i video.mp4 -map 0 -c copy seg1.mp4
ffmpeg -ss 00:00:04 -i video.mp4 -map 0 -c copy seg2.mp4
```

than we can concatenate their:

Create file 1.txt with:

file 'seg1.mp4'

file 'seg2.mp4'

and run that

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i 1.txt -map 0 -c copy out.mp4
```

Note, we have to calculate time stamps from frame numbers to time in -t and -ss options